# Adhesion energy vs free energy of solvation

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-chemistry, surface-chemistry

I am looking to compute the solvation free energy of Pt(111). Experimental data are still rare because the entropic term is hard to measure.

I have found a [paper](https://chemrxiv.org/engage/chemrxiv/article-details/60c74fb4ee301c255dc7a741) where they use a QM/MM approach to compute the free energy of solvation of Pt(111), they compare their result to the value of 0.32 J/m2 given in [Singh, N., Campbell, C.T., 2019. ACS Catal. 9, 8116–8127.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acscatal.9b01870)

However in this last paper they describe the value as "Water−Pt(111) Bond Energy (i.e., Adhesion Energy)." which in my understanding does not contains any entropic information.

I am confused that the first paper use the term of solvation free energy and compares it to a paper which only computes bond energy, am I missing something?